# WordPress: PHP Fatal Error... Allowed memory size exhauted

Tags: php, wordpress, fatal-error, ram, data-handling

Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 536870912 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 20480 bytes) in /var/www/web24689573/html/wp-includes/meta.php on line 841

```
Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 536870912 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 20480 bytes) in /var/www/web24689573/html/wp-includes/plugin.php on line 449
```

The reason why I get this error is, because I handle a lot of datas to set prices and etc. in WordPress. At the moment for over 5000 products and each product can have multiple prices (price comparsion). Plus, every product need to be assigned to a category and stuff like this. So, I have many request via PHP with WordPress.

I know that this error doesn't comes from the script itselfs. My question now is, what would you advise me to do?

I already disabled the cache and things like that as you can see here:

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'jb_pre_get_posts' );
function jb_pre_get_posts( WP_Query $wp_query ) {
    if ( in_array( $wp_query->get( 'post_type' ), array( 'my_post_type_1', 'my_post_type_2' ) ) ) {
        $wp_query->set( 'update_post_meta_cache', false );
    }
}
```

Here you can read why this error comes: http://www.junaidbhura.com/wordpress-admin-fix-fatal-error-allowed-memory-size-error/

But I think now I am nearly at the limit of the RAM (4GB). Would be very thankful about your advises and tips.

Greetings

Comment: Have you tried `define( 'WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '64M' );` this one?

Comment: Already defined at 512MB

Answer (score 0):

the error says that your memory size is not enough even with 512MB, try to set memory_limit to 2048M in wp-config.php. if you can get access to php.ini file you can update the memory_limit and restart php